"Tagging" timestamps in Godot Animation Player
Is there a way to add 'tags' to the timeline of godot?
I want to be able to tag certain timestamps in my godot animation player, and possibly query for the previous/next timestamps
I've tried using "call" track to simulate tags (i.e. by calling code) but it doesn't really allow for querying the timestamps

So, it looks like there is a PR out to add markers https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/91765
There is also this issue related to this problem https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/8414
Those may take some time to merge into Godot, so in the meantime, using call functions will probably be the best bet.
You can pass in parameters from the call function, which may help with what you want to do. You can also hard code variables in code with the time stamp in it.
It might be helpful to know your end goal to see if there's a better way to solving it, but at least this should be a head start.
Hope this helps!

Thanks! Yeah this is super helpful, and I hope that the PR will be added soon.
My end goal is actually to make a simple 'on rails light gun' shooter (think Time Crisis, or The House of the Dead). Being able to add 'tags' to certain positions in the timeline as say 'hiding spots' would be really useful.
I was able to work with simply using call functions, but it's quite cumbersome. In particular, it would be great to just name sections/points, and also go to prev/next marker through a simple API.

I see, good luck on it! I love on rail shooters. The HotD remake was a ton of fun, I hope they remake 2 and 3. 3 especially as that was my childhood favorite on OG xbox haha.
